# How to implement @RequestMapping custom properties

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

As an **example**, take **subdomain mapping**.

This article: [Managing multiple Domain and Sub Domain on Google App Engine for Same Application](http://techsravi.blogspot.com/2011/05/managing-multiple-domain-and-sub-domain.html)
recommends to resolve subdomain on Filter and assign variable to ServletRequest headers.

Then the mapping will look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", headers="subdomain=www")
 public String subsiteIndexPage(Model model,HttpServletRequest request) { ... }
```

If we'd like to create custom @RequestMapping property, such as subdomain, eg. to create mapping like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some/action", subdomain = "www")
public String handlerFunction(){ ... }
```

we should override `@RequestMapping @interface` definition and **override RequestMappingHandlerMapping** protected methods, with our own implementation
(as stated on JIRA: "[Allow custom request mapping conditions SPR-7812](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7812)").

Is it right? Can anybody provide a hint, how to achieve this functionality?

---

**Idea 1**:
As suggested on original jira thread, is to create own implementation of `RequestCondition`

There is an project which uses this solution available on github: https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-31-demo/

And related SO question: [Adding custom RequestCondition's in Spring mvc 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073695/adding-custom-requestconditions-in-spring-mvc-3-1)

Maybe mapping like `@Subdomain("www")` for both Type and Method, is possible solution?

---

[Link to same question on forum.springsource.com](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?125780-RequestMapping-custom-properties&p=410574)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I've created solution based on referenced [spring-mvc-31-demo](https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-31-demo/)

> This solution can be used to map only single RequestCondition as of now. I've created two Issues to notify, this should be changed:
>   https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-31-demo/issues/5
>   https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9350

**This solution uses custom @RequestCondition feature of Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE platform**

**USAGE**

Example 1:

```
@Controller
@SubdomainMapping(value = "subdomain", tld = ".mydomain.com")
class MyController1 {
    // Code here will be executed only on address match:
    // subdomain.mydomain.com
}
```

Example 2:

```
@Controller
class MyController2 {

    @RequestMapping("/index.html")
    @SubdomainMapping("www")
    public function index_www(Map<Object, String> map){
        // on www.domain.com
        // where ".domain.com" is defined in SubdomainMapping.java
    }

    @RequestMapping("/index.html")
    @SubdomainMapping("custom")
    public function index_custom(Map<Object, String> map){
        // on custom.domain.com
        // where ".domain.com" is defined in SubdomainMapping.java
    }
}
```

We need three files

- SubdomainMapping.java
- SubdomainRequestCondition.java
- SubdomainRequestMappingHandlerMapping.java

**SubdomainMapping.java**

```
import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SubdomainMapping {

    /**
    * This param defines single or multiple subdomain
    * Where the Method/Type is valid to be called
    */
    String[] value() default {};
    /**
    * This param defines site domain and tld
    * It's important to put the leading dot
    * Not an array, so cannot be used for mapping multiple domains/tld
    */
    String tld() default ".custom.tld";
}
```

**SubdomainRequestCondition.java**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.RequestCondition;

public class SubdomainRequestCondition implements
        RequestCondition<SubdomainRequestCondition> {

    private final Set<String> subdomains;
    private final String tld;

    public SubdomainRequestCondition(String tld, String... subdomains) {
        this(tld, Arrays.asList(subdomains));
    }

    public SubdomainRequestCondition(String tld, Collection<String> subdomains) {
        this.subdomains = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>(
                subdomains));
        this.tld = tld;
    }

    @Override
    public SubdomainRequestCondition combine(SubdomainRequestCondition other) {
        Set<String> allRoles = new LinkedHashSet<String>(this.subdomains);
        allRoles.addAll(other.subdomains);
        return new SubdomainRequestCondition(tld, allRoles);
    }

    @Override
    public SubdomainRequestCondition getMatchingCondition(
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            URL uri = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString());
            String[] parts = uri.getHost().split(this.tld);
            if (parts.length == 1) {
                for (String s : this.subdomains) {
                    if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(parts[0])) {
                        return this;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SubdomainRequestCondition other,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        return org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils.removeAll(other.subdomains, this.subdomains).size();
    }

}
```

**SubdomainRequestMappingHandlerMapping.java**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.RequestCondition;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping;

public class CustomRequestMappingHandlerMapping extends
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping {

    @Override
    protected RequestCondition<?> getCustomTypeCondition(Class<?> handlerType) {
        SubdomainMapping typeAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(
                handlerType, SubdomainMapping.class);
        return createCondition(typeAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    protected RequestCondition<?> getCustomMethodCondition(Method method) {
        SubdomainMapping methodAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(
                method, SubdomainMapping.class);
        return createCondition(methodAnnotation);
    }

    private RequestCondition<?> createCondition(SubdomainMapping accessMapping) {
        return (accessMapping != null) ? new SubdomainRequestCondition(
                accessMapping.tld(), accessMapping.value()) : null;
    }

}
```

**Instalation**

> IMPORTANT: So far, it is not possible to use this solution with XML element
>   **<mvc:annotation-driven />**, see JIRA https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9344 for explanation

- You have to register custom MappingHandler bean, pointing at this custom implementation `SubdomainRequestMappingHandlerMapping` class
- You have to set it's order to be lower than default `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`
  **OR**
  Replace the registered `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` (possibly on order=0)

**For more wide explanation on implementing this solution, see the related github project**

Comment: To solve the problem with <mvc:annotation-driven />, you can replace it with java based config by extending WebMvcConfigurationSupport (read the javadoc in @EnableWebMvc, jump straight to the last case)

Comment: For a xml based alternative to <mvc:annotation-driven />, check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693397/howto-get-rid-of-mvcannotation-driven

Comment: Could I use this approach for request mapping depends on condition from request body?

Comment: @WakaWaka you should be able to use similar approach

Comment: I have implemented the same thing, @Vituel do you have any example to achieve the annotation thing using XML. current defining the annotation directly in class works well.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, but that would be too complicated. You'd better check the `Host` header, whether it contains a given subdomain.

But you should not really need this more than once or twice, so you can also do it manually in the method body. If you really need it in many places, it would be an odd requirement.

Comment: odd in which way? It gives me probably better control, than many Url Rewrite rules. Like If you have a platform, and you need to differentiate actions based on authenticated role (admin, manager, user) and you can have mappings such as `/admin/*`, `/manager/*`, etc.. or you can have `admin.domain.tld/*`, `manager.domain.tld/*`, ...

Comment: Please see suggestion 1 in question. Maybe this could be elegant solution

Comment: Can you think about some nicer implementation of @RequestCondition than extending RequestMappingHandlerMapping ?

Comment: as far as I see, no. Though I would assume you should be able to plug your implementation in some list somehwre. But I can't find it

Comment: I've put my own solution to this question, please consider making any updates and/or improvements to my code. Thanks