# Spring @RequestMapping headers OR instead of AND?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My project consist of many types of sites, like a blog and a forum and a site.

I have specific controllers for the blog, forum and site (and a lot more)

Certain controllers i wish to share between types of site, for example the login controller.

But i only want the login controller to be shared with forum and site.

I use a filter to add a request header "partType" which has value site, forum or blog.

My @RequestMapping of my login controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/dash/login",  headers={"partType=forum","partType=site" })
```

This results in mapping:

```
{[/dash/login/dologin],methods=[GET || POST],headers=[partType=forum && partType=site]}
```

Notice the && (and). Is it possible to get an || (or) in here?

Because the "partType" header is never a forum and a site, but i do want the logincontroller to support partType forum and site, but not blog, so i can't just remove the header attribute from the requestmapping annotation.

Comment: Not with the defaults you would have to write your own rules for that and rewrite part of the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` for them to get configured.

Comment: Cheers @M. Deinum , indeed i was already looking at RequestMappingHandlerMapping but the problem with overriding this one is that mvc:annotation-driven is disabled when doing so, rendering all the nice things of spring finding controllers and methods useless. There is a trick when using java config, but i'm still stuck with xml config.

Comment: On an side note: i found a suboptimal solution, using an interceptor preHandle() to append "partType" to the uri and using RequestDispatcher to forward the request with the new uri. This works but i'm worried about the performance hit, cause every request now gets forwarded by the RequestDispatcher.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you use XML or Java based configuration the solution is the same. Detecting controllers is done by component scanning and what actually processes them is the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` so no there isn't an issue (apart from loosing the default configured and detected things from the namespace/annotation).

Comment: The easiest solution is to create 2 handler mapping methods one for each header and let them call the same (internal) method on the controller.

Comment: Thanks @M. Deinum  for the hints and tips! I just posted a reply explaining how i solved it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sure was a journey through the inner workings of spring mvc. While i was browsing the source code of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`  in noticed that `createRequestMappingInfo` looked for `RequestCondition` on the Controller.

Looking a bit further into the `RequestCondition` thing i noticed that the default `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` does nothing with it. While searching online why it ignores `RequestCondition` i found this post:
[How to implement @RequestMapping custom properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312177/how-to-implement-requestmapping-custom-properties)

This first answer gives a example of `RequestCondition` and extending `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. But extending `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` means not having `<mvc:annotation-driven />`.

I messed around with `BeanPostProcessor` and got that working with a custom `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`, but writing a wrapper around an existing instance of `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` is not possible.

Lucky i surfed back to the above url and read the comments which link to a post:
[Howto get rid of <mvc:annotation-driven />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693397/howto-get-rid-of-mvcannotation-driven)
This one explains how to replace `<mvc:annotation-driven />` with custom xml that does the same thing, but allowing to set the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`.

After a bit of fiddling around it now works!

Answer (score 0):

Try using **headers=["partType=forum,site"]**, it might work.
It works when you are setting the **content-type=application/json,application/xml**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i just gave it a shot but it doesn't work. When using "partType=forum,site" the header needs to be "partType=forum,site". The , (comma) is ignored and it not threaded as OR. I suspect the "content-type" does something magical.