# Spring Boot Loading Sub Class of a Controller from Interceptor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to intercept the request and change the controller on the basis of a domain.

My Application Structure:

- Base

  - controllers

    - IndexController
- domain

  - domain-one

    - controllers

      - IndexController `<- Extends the base.controller.IndexController`

Now if the request comes from a domain which is domain.one then `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` should load the subclass of the IndexController which is located in this namespace `domain-one.controllers.IndexController`

I'm able to get the subclass by using the `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider` for example in `preHandle` method:

```java
HashMap<String, String> domains = config.getDomain(); // <-- This gives me the domain name list with mapped directory in domain directory

String domain = request.getHeader("host").split(":")[0];

if(! domains.containsKey(domain) ) { // If domain mapping not exist then use the default one.
    return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
}

String contextDir = domains.get(domain); // <-- this will return domain-one String
String controllerNamespace = "domain.";
Object handlerMethod = ((HandlerMethod) handler).getBean();
classPathFinder.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(handlerMethod.getClass()));
Set<BeanDefinition> components = classPathFinder.findCandidateComponents(controllerNamespace + contextDir);

BeanDefinition controllerBean = components.iterator().next(); // Found 1 BeanDifinition in the domain-one controller directory

String newControllerClassPath = ((ScannedGenericBeanDefinition)controllerBean).getMetadata().getClassName(); // This will return the complete class namespace like: domain.domain-one.controller.IndexController
```

Now how can I tell the preHandle method to use the `newControllerClassPath` as a controller for this request? I know I need to create an object of it but after that what should I do

if I do `return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);` it will load the existing controller but I need to change the `handler` object before returning the `super.prehandle` from the method.

Basically what I'm trying to do is to implement kind of a [multi-domain architecture](https://oneshoe.com/blog/multi-site-vs-multi-domain-solution-differences)

I hope I have cleared my question.

Comment: Can't you simply narrow the mappings by specifying header value in the `@RequestMapping` definitions is the individual controllers https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping. Or use a custom property on the request mappings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312177/how-to-implement-requestmapping-custom-properties

Comment: np, because that will create complexity, I'm making this behavior because I have multiple domains, if for that domain controller is not exist then it should go to the default one.

Comment: *because that will create complexity*. As opposed to your current proposal!!

Comment: @AlanHay thanks for the comment the below URL really helps me to achieve what I was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/10336769/1635676