# Spring security hasAnyRole and different flows for different permissions

Tags: spring, spring-security

In my Spring Boot application I have a REST controller with a following method:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('PERMISSION_UPDATE_OWN_COMMENT', 'PERMISSION_UPDATE_ANY_COMMENT')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public CommentResponse updateComment(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user, @Valid @RequestBody UpdateCommentRequest commentRequest) {
    Comment comment = commentService.updateComment(commentRequest.getCommentId(), commentRequest.getTitle(), commentRequest.getContent(), user);
    return new CommentResponse(comment);
}
```

Only users with `PERMISSION_UPDATE_OWN_COMMENT` or `PERMISSION_UPDATE_ANY_COMMENT` are allowed to use this endpoint.

Inside of this method I need to create two different flows - one for users with `PERMISSION_UPDATE_OWN_COMMENT` and another one for users with `PERMISSION_UPDATE_ANY_COMMENT`permissions.

So my question is - what is best practice for Spring security in order to implement these different flows of logic inside of the single method ?

Should I validate inside of the `updateComment` method that the user has one or another permission and based on this condition implement my logic ?

Comment: Another approach would be to extend the request mapping mechanism so that you could implement a separate method for each role. See here for a starting point:http://stackoverflow.com/a/18313976/1356423. There also seems to be a project here with an example of a custom 'RoleMapping' annotation which seems exactly what you need. https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-31-demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to do the logic inside updateComment function inside controller. Because, you can easily get the instance of `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` from the action param to find the role.

But the **best practice is to put your logic inside service**. This will make your life easier to reuse the logic in another place like `RESTFul APIs`.

So you may use the below code or something similar to check the role inside the Service.

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = authentication.getAuthorities();
boolean authorized = authorities.contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("PERMISSION_UPDATE_OWN_COMMENT"));
```

**(edited with further information)**

Complete function which can be used to check the `roles`

```
protected boolean roleExist(String role) {
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
    for (GrantedAuthority auth : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
        if (role.equals(auth.getAuthority()))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll follow this way ! One more question, how to get authentication inside of my service class.. or may be method ?

Comment: You can get it from SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(). Wait I will update the answer with the complete function which you can use. :)