# How to check for unbound request parameters in a Spring MVC controller method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, parameters, controller

Given a Spring-MVC controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method")
public void method(ParamModel params) { /*...*/ }
```

with model class:

```
public class ParamModel { public int param1; }
```

The following two results are as expected/desired:

- Request with `param1=1`: `method` completes successfully.
- Request with `param1=blah`: `JBWEB000120: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`

However...

- If a request is made with an additional parameter (e.g. `nonexistentparam=1`), **there is no error**.

Is there a way to ensure the request is validated and rejected if it includes any parameters that aren't part of this API?

Comment: I haven't seen the need to do this myself, and I couldn't find any documentation directly addressing it, but it seems that you may need to configure (or subclass) the container's `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`.

Comment: How to distinguish between request params that are invalid from valid ones? The fact that a request parameter is not mapped to a controller param does not mean that it is an invalid request param, because there might be other components that use it, e.g. servlet filters or it is simply passed through and rendered in a hidden field again.

Comment: @chrylis The need to do this is driven by a split client/server development. I'm working on an API on the server side that is subject to change and would like the client requests to break if for example a parameter is renamed or deprecated (rather than silently ignoring them).

Comment: @SteveChambers If this is REST-based, a simpler and more reliable way to handle API changes is to version the media types that you're using.

Comment: @chrylis Not sure I understand exactly what you mean but let's say the above ParamModel was somehow versioned as 1.0. If a client called version 1.0 but erroneously passed in a parameter that isn't part of ParamModel, I'd like it to report an error. Not sure how versioning solves this?

Comment: @RenéLink Good point - have now changed the title to "check for *unbound* parameters"

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter to check for invalid parameters as

***web.xml***

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.mypackage.filter.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

***MyFilter Class***

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String requestUrl = request.getParameter("param1");
    //here I am considering 'param1=1' as valid request rest of all are invalid
             if(!requestUrl.equals("1")) {
        logger.info("Invalid Request"); 
        //for invalid request redirect to error or login page
        response.sendRedirect("/error"");           
    } else {
        logger.info("Valid Request");   
    }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }       

}
```

hope this will solve your problem

Comment: This is a generic "do something" answer that doesn't at all address how to configure Spring to raise an error if there are extra parameters not defined in the model class.

Answer (score 0):

A good practice will be Bean-Validation (JSR-303). here is the [Document](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html)

keep it simple, you need have this in your spring config:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

and you can have this in your code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/method")
public void method(@Valid ParamModel params, BindingResult result) {
    if(result.hasErrors()) {...}
    else {...}
}

public class ParamModel { 
    @SomeAnnotation // details see document 
    private int param1; 
}
```

Comment: While Bean Validation is useful, this doesn't answer this question, which is how to get Spring to raise an error if extra HTTP parameters are sent. Bean Validation happens after they're set onto a model object.

Answer (score 0):

Spring's [@RequestMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) takes a "params" parameter.

Documentation:

> The parameters of the mapped request, narrowing the primary mapping.
>
> Same format for any environment: a sequence of "myParam=myValue" style
>   expressions, with a request only mapped if each such parameter is
>   found to have the given value. Expressions can be negated by using the
>   "!=" operator, as in "myParam!=myValue". "myParam" style expressions
>   are also supported, with such parameters having to be present in the
>   request (allowed to have any value). Finally, "!myParam" style
>   expressions indicate that the specified parameter is not supposed to
>   be present in the request.

Another possiblity is to use [PathVariable](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) (always required) or [RequestParam](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) with parameter *required=true*.

**Update:**

You could create your own request mapping conditions by subclassing [RequestMappingHandlerMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html) and overriding getCustomMethodCondition/getCustomTypeCondition.

However the XML configuration `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` cannot be used as that also declares this Bean and you would end up with 2 handler mappings.
Look at [Adding custom RequestCondition's in Spring mvc 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073695/adding-custom-requestconditions-in-spring-mvc-3-1) for details.

Comment: He wants to reject *all* unmatched parameters. The mapping conditions allow you to specify parameters that will prevent a match.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious, boring and non-Springish option would be to use:

```
@RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams
```

... and check the list of parameters for yourself. It of course requires you to parse (to integer, etc.) and validate the values manually instead of using a DTO and/or javax.validation annotations.

Full example (requires mapping the InvalidParamsException to a status code):

```
@GetMapping("/my_strict_api")
public void myStrictApi(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams) {
  Set<String> allowed = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("cat", "dog"));
  if (!allowed.containsAll(allRequestParams.keySet())) {
    throw new InvalidParamsException("We only accept: " + allowed.toString());
  }
  // You should also validate the parameter values before using them
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to override controllers request methods invocations:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcRegistrations mvcRegistrations() {
  return new WebMvcRegistrationsAdapter() {
    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter getRequestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
      return new RequestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
        private ParameterNameDiscoverer parameterNameDiscoverer = new DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer();

        @Override
        protected ServletInvocableHandlerMethod createInvocableHandlerMethod(HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
          return new ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(handlerMethod) {
            Set<String> boundParametersNames = Stream.of(getMethodParameters())
                .map(methodParameter -> {
                  methodParameter.initParameterNameDiscovery(parameterNameDiscoverer);
                  return methodParameter.getParameterName();
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

            @Override
            public Object invokeForRequest(NativeWebRequest request,
                                           ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
                                           Object... providedArgs) throws Exception {
              for (Iterator<String> iterator = request.getParameterNames(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
                String parameterName = iterator.next();
                if (!boundParametersNames.contains(parameterName)) {
                  return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(null);
                }
              }
              return super.invokeForRequest(request, mavContainer, providedArgs);
            }
          };
        }
      };
    }
  };
}
```

In a InvocableHandlerMethod both request parameters and method parameters can be easily accessed and verified.